# How to save downloaded images with a specific name?

Tags: python, dataframe, download, python-requests

I have this code that is looping through a `df` (excel file) and creates the link for the image to be saved.
The code works in creating the links for the images but I can't save the image with the links name found in my `df`,

For example:

```
/images/S/aplus-media/vc/9c4fd284-2d51-47d8-8275-9977cc5f9771.jpg
```

```
lst = just_img_col.values.tolist()

var = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/'

for val in lst:
    for ele in val:
      if len(str(ele)) > 10:
        image_url = var + str(ele)
        print(image_url)
        r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
        filename = str(ele)
        print(filename)

 if r.status_code == 200:
    r.raw.decode_content = True

# Open a local file with wb ( write binary ) permission.
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ', filename)
else:
   print('Image Couldn\'t be retreived')
```

Is there anything I should add to my code so that I can save the images with a name in this format:
`/images/S/aplus-media/vc/9c4fd284-2d51-47d8-8275-9977cc5f9771.jpg`?

Some examples of links:

```
https://m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/vc/aa7c7a6e-6ad8-4f14-997a-49b379fae2b4.jpg
https://m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/vc/9eff75e4-c9b2-4fc6-8f88-5a8ac57d5aca.jpg
https://m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/sota/bb556924-6691-4510-82aa-e13360fb5acf.jpg
https://m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/vc/2e87df92-06e3-4fc2-9781-86f0e50ac867.jpg
https://m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/vc/6bcafb85-8836-43ef-9d18-da3ce64b4e0b.jpg
```

Comment: what is `image_url`?

Comment: @Epsi95 it is the name from my file (which I need to have as the name of the image saved), concatenated with var (var =  'https: //m.media-amazon.com/')   this one for eg https: //m.media-amazon.com//images/S/aplus-media/vc/9c4fd284-2d51-47d8-8275-9977cc5f9771.jpg

Comment: `shutil.copyfileobj` doesn't do what you think it does. You should use `f.write(r.raw)` and don't forget to close your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure `var` and `ele` has the following structure. It seems you are messing with forward slash `/`. Try `printing` the `image_url` before the GET request.

```py
import os
import requests


var = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/'
lst = [['/images/S/aplus-media/vc/9c4fd284-2d51-47d8-8275-9977cc5f9771.jpg']]

for val in lst:
    for ele in val:
        if len(str(ele)) > 10:
            image_url = os.path.join(var[:-1], str(ele)[1:])
            print(image_url)
            r = requests.get(image_url)
            filename = str(ele).replace('/', '_')
            

            if r.status_code == 200:
                # r.raw.decode_content = True
                # Open a local file with wb ( write binary ) permission.
                with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)

                print('Image sucessfully Downloaded: ', filename)
            else:
                print('Image Couldn\'t be retreived')
```

Comment: thank you! How should I modify with open('image.png', 'wb') as f ---'image.png' here in order to save each image with its name from my df?

Comment: give some sample of `lst`, then I can provide full code

Comment: I have updated the description with some examples of links that need to be downloaded. image_url is the full link while ele is this part of the link:   /images/S/aplus-media/vc/9c4fd284-2d51-47d8-8275-9977cc5f9771.jpg  which, is found in my df and should be the name of the image saved. Basically, the ele value should be the name

Comment: you can create a file name as `a/b/c/d.jpg`, it will create a filder a, then a filder b, then a folder c the file d.jpg. Your file name should be a_b_c_d.jpg

Comment: @Sergio try this